# Get rid of "smart quotes" in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2003, smart-quotes

I'm not sure what I did, but the quotes (single and double) in Outlook 2003 have gone from straight vertical quotes to angled quotes. I've looked through Outlook's options and the Autocorrect options, and I can't seem to find anything that would enable/disable this feature?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>'</kbd> to turn this feature on or off.

The shortcut is undocumented (it doesn't appear in [Keyboard shortcuts](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/keyboard-shortcuts-HP003084223.aspx)), and I'd say it's pretty easy to enable by mistake...

Comment: Yup, that was it! Thanks!! :) Is this (or similar "hidden" features) documented anywhere?

Comment: No, as it appears. At least, it does not appear in the offical list of shorcuts ([link](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook-help/keyboard-shortcuts-HP003084223.aspx?CTT=1)).