# Enable modification of AutoCorrect options in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office

I installed Outlook 2013 without installing any* other Microsoft Office products and was noticing that the AutoCorrect feature was not behaving like I had remembered it. So, I went to see what had changed in the AutoCorrect options (**File > Options > Mail > Editor Options... > Proofing > AutoCorrect Options...**) and found that I could only view the first tab and could only modify the *Replace text as you type* section.

<sub>*: Of course the installation came with a few additional pieces of software I neither wanted nor needed.</sub>

[image: Outlook AutoCorrect options disabled]

Which setting do I need to change to enable access to these options?

Comment: Specifically, [the enabling of the Smart Quotes feature](https://superuser.com/q/384329/45163) drove me to this investigation.

Answer (score 0):

From [a discussion on a Microsoft forum](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/c8cc3764-2679-4931-9e38-c26d01b7118d/auto-correct-wont-allow-changes-to-options-outlook-2013?forum=outlook), the folder with your Outlook executable has to also contain a Word executable. From another system with Microsoft Word 2010 on it, and I copied the `WINWORD.EXE` file (`%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft Office\Office14\WINWORD.EXE`) from that system to the system in question.

Though I didn't try this with any other version of Word, but I would guess any version of the Word executable from 2007-2016 would suffice to enable these options.

Comment: I can understand that Outlook uses the Word AutoCorrect logic, but that it doesn't come in a shared library, but requires the executable itself baffles me.